Maxent Species Distribution Modelling in R: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)
I have two dataframes with 15,695 rows, and they have no NAs:

dat_Winter: contains environmental variables
dolphin_coords_xy: contains longitude and latitude positions in decimal degrees

I am trying to run a Maxent model using the function maxent() from the dismo package. Whenever I run the maxent model, I keep on getting this error message (below).
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0

This message means that I'm trying to create a data.frame from vectors or columns that have a mismatched number of rows. However, both data frames have the same number of rows.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error message as I've met the requirements of 'x' and 'p', I have no NA's, the rows aren't mismatched in theory. Am I missing something?
I can't share the data due to ownership issues but I can provide a copy of the first 5 rows to show what my data looks like and some dummy data.
#Select the presence points from the dataframe 'dolphin_coords1"
dolphin_coords_xy <- dolphin_coords1 %>% dplyr::select(1, 2)
dolphin_coords_xy<-as.data.frame(dolphin_coords_xy)
p=dolphin_coords_xy


 #make model 
 max1_Winter <- maxent(x = dat_Winter, p = dolphin_coords_xy)

#------------Do some troubleshooting--------------------------

#Check that the rows are of equal length
nrow(dat_Winter) #15695 rows 
nrow(dolphin_coords_xy) #15695 rows 

# Check for NA values in columns
sum(is.na(dolphin_coords_xy$x))  # Count NA values (NAs = 0)
sum(is.na(dolphin_coords_xy$y))  # Count NA values (NAs = 0)

#Check the class of the two data frames
class(dat_Winter) #data.frame
class(dolphin_coords_xy) #dataframe

#Check Requirements
 x = Predictors can either be a Raster* object or SpatialGridDataFrame 
 or a dataframe, in which each column should be a predictor variable and 
 each row a presence or background record

 p = If p is a data.frame or matrix it represents a set of point locations; 
 and it must have two columns with the first being the x-coordinate (longitude) 
 and the second the y-coordinate (latitude). 

Dataframe 1 dat_Winter:
         SST   Chlor.a       Slope  Distance Depth
1   26.03596 0.2764387  3.12927913    0.0000     5
2   25.84813 0.3505107  0.54305966  412.0501     9
3   25.79146 0.3326796  0.96003758 4175.7593    62
4   26.03121 0.2818667  2.14737457  412.5744     5
5   26.03596 0.2764387  3.12927913    0.0000     5

Dataframe 2 coords_dolphins_xy:
         x        y
1   33.89083 27.26778
2   33.86782 27.40854
3   33.86230 27.44623
4   33.88653 27.26957
5   33.88766 27.26848

Dummy data:
structure(list(x = c(33.7250201948918, 33.0372212855145, 33.1162582356483, 
33.1780943416525, 33.325465941336, 33.1426498885266, 33.372344966745, 
33.7141977476422, 33.5114065359812, 33.4723861014936), y = c(28.0621412244625, 
27.6205332666635, 28.0223171819933, 27.5313555219211, 27.1894561205059, 
27.5307895665988, 28.1612804006785, 27.5815055153333, 27.3029501273297, 
27.3116279762238), Calf_Presence = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), SSS = c(1027.47942044867, 1026.32734772185, 1027.6889518555, 
1026.61821882308, 1026.73625519967, 1026.99284255489, 1026.50956621722, 
1026.42982337421, 1026.87068500051, 1026.71667900492), SST = c(25.0228688765572, 
27.6068648373514, 23.5967889237256, 26.6370548686025, 26.2696984540073, 
24.8069121214026, 27.1928669289746, 27.3427573793279, 26.2358166318412, 
26.8545404103531), Chlor.a = c(0.234918360422555, 0.552972766326481, 
0.372645556572673, 0.158839964433605, 0.155691480776937, 0.322592780862786, 
0.16285265978558, 0.155731527084381, 0.207670826649629, 0.174525638280348
), Slope = c(4.50732010781271, 0.262136190366096, 0.164475474050542, 
0.725271958307515, 0.793811857372093, 0.0233933381961778, 2.86868026925737, 
2.04465639865241, 1.15032474698361, 0.930412189550645), Distance = c(102293.714232872, 
332276.294160756, 126047.003446403, 146918.398130579, 158796.57696904, 
27015.5468157929, 190039.211871486, 265043.121310163, 105894.776220919, 
98221.3073956403), Depth = c(27, 2, 52, 810, 1081, 76, 819, 879, 
705, 738)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


In max1_Winter <-  p = dolphin_coords1 is assigned, whereas in nrow checks, dolphin_coords_xy is queried...And, are there any duplicate rows, as it appears these are checked for and removed that may account for different number orfrows in one or other of x or p as one might then want to cbind them...

Thanks for giving me this information Chris. Could you please explain what p = coords1 is assigned means and dolphin_corrds_xy is queried means. I'm confused because I'm using maxent() instead of <-. Do you know how I could fix this? Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction

The error is a standard data.frame (creation) error, and with removeDuplicates=TRUE the default in maxext, checking for those via anyDuplicated is the last avenue to check. Handily it returns index of duplicates. Removing such from x & p, or if x also p, or if p also x, then checking again on nrow for each may get us out of the woods. And removal is likely for statistical integrity to avoid inadvertent thumb on the scale oversampling.

max1_Winter <- maxent(x=dat_Winter, p = dolphin_coords_xy, removeDuplicates=TRUE)

This command returns the same error: max1_Winter <- maxent(x=dat_Winter, p = dolphin_coords_xy, removeDuplicates=TRUE)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0

I've got to get the analysis for my poster finished by today and I just can't figure this out. I don't understand! I've been using chatgpt and I've been doing this for 5 hours now using all kinds of combinations of code that it is suggesting. I keep on getting the same error message

Before using the input data.frames, do the anyDuplicated test and remove as indicated, if found in x, also remove from p, if found in p also remove rows from x. Check nrow again. Then send them through maxext. Best I can think of. I get the sense that removeDuplicates isn't also providing the service of further balancing x and p, ie. do they have same # of rows in what seems like being sent for interpretation as 1 data.frame.

anyDuplicated(dat_Winter) = 5, anyDuplicated(dolphin_coords_xy) = 11

Does the mean I need to remove rows 5 and 11 from both dataframe?

That would be my best guess as if means nrow(x) == nrow(p) after .

I just ran #Create a new dataframe which doesn't have any duplicates
dat_s1<-as.data.frame(my_df_no_duplicates) and nrow(dat_s1) *15325 rows, I put the dataframes with no dubplicates back into the Maxent model and I'm still getting the same error message.

I ran this test on the dataframe before I split it up into the two dataframes again. Neigher has NAs, duplicates, or differing number of rows. I don't know! I also get the same error message with the dummy data.

Perhaps we're contending with garbage collection or some artifact and start process in new session...Now feeling as breathless as you without the benefit of the Aussie beaches.

Have you been trying with the dummy data and getting the same error message? This works but it doesn't make sense - #make model w two les layer
max1 <- maxent(x = dat_Winter, p = dolphin_coords1$Calf_Presence),
path = "/Users//Desktop/Master/Model/maxent")

I'm putting a vector of 0's and 1's for calf presence and calf absence but the maxent model needs long and lat coordainates

Sticking with the de-duplicated data, have you tried stepping through debugonce(maxent) a couple of times to see where the error is triggered, on second pass checking/testing on all ls()  objects present just before it is triggered to get dim, nrow, anyDuplicated... to discern what's going on?

No! That wouldn't have crossed my mind! How can I do that?

1: debugonce(maxent) puts you in debug mode (browser), once as it says. s{return} steps to next step in function, n is next (function, or line), c is continue, Q is quit. so, debugonce(maxent), then max1_Winter <- maxent(x = dat_Winter, p = dolphin_coords_xy) throws you into  browser, n {return} till it throws error, while you count how many n(s). then debugonce(maxent) same as before and n-1 returns, ls() gives you all objects present, look at each one....scratch head. In this instance its not maxent that isn't working properly by data it is asked to consume.

Once you've established n{return} -1, debugonce, once again to n-1 and you can advance in smaller steps using s, and ls() and tests, up to  (and including throwing error). s-ing through a function can be quite time consuming, esp if there are side trips through other, long complex functions...

Hey Chris. Thank you for your patience and advice. I soled the problem wtih my colleague. It's because some of the absence points were on land. It was a painful process. However, i learnt a lot, which is the main thing. You can only get better with practive. I used QGIS and deleted the absence points and now the Maxent model is working just fine

And a condition that hadn't occurred to me. Following tradition here, you'd answer your question below and accept it for others in the future. We can also judiciously delete some of our comments here. Happy it was solved.

Was there anything in the p characteristics that indicated 'land' or was that arrived at simply via lon/lat mapping?

Just simply long/lat mapping. After the conference when I have a spare moment, I will answer my own question and give instructions with how ot cut the points on land with QGIS with images, then I'll add images.

I really should RTM SDM-Hijmans prior to attempting help, Chapter 2 on location data cleaning within R for gbif files.
